# Excel: Sum different types of shifts

Tags: excel

I'm not sure if this is easily possible but any help will do. I have a column with different shifts in the format xx:xx-xx:xx. Morning shifts are normally 07:00-16:00 and evenings are 12:00-20:00. There are variations, like morning finishing 30 minutes to an hour later and evenings starting 30 minutes to an hour earlier.

I want to automate it so under the column there is a cell which tells me the total number of people on a morning shift and evening shift. I've used TIMEVALUE to convert this TEXT value to a numeric value, what would be my next steps? I've tried working with IF's but it doesn't work with how I do them.

Tried using TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(cell,5)) to get the finishing times but not sure how to increase the value of the cell with each truth.

Example:

```
           Monday
Employee1  07:00-16:00
Employee2
Employee3  07:00-16:00
Employee4  12:00-20:00
Employee5  12:00-20:00
Employee6
```

As shown, some will be on morning shifts and some on evenings and some won't be working. Is there a way to have 2 cells below this column, one which has the total number of morning shift and one with total number of evening without me having to manually enter them?

Comment: Without decent example data COUNTIFS()

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry, please check edit for an example

Comment: How did you get on applying countifs()?

Comment: @SolarMike tried something but can't make it work with TIMEVALUE

Comment: Then show how you used TIMEVALUE with countifs()

Comment: @SolarMike coming off your screenshot you had in your answer, I did =COUNTIF(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(D4:D8,5))),"<=17")

Comment: Perhaps my method is shorter and I go for the start time, also I don't convert with TIMEVALUE().

Answer (score 1):

So, a quick attempt just to get Morning or Evening:

[image]
You can add to deal with the early starts.

The vlookup method is another option. Then you can use index() with match() to get names etc

So, further update:

[image]

Comment: Okay I understand what you did there, but is there a way to tally without having a column showing morning evening morning etc.? Or would I just have to hide that column and have a tally in B9 which counts the instances of morning and evening?

Comment: @ZainMohamed use the simple functions of count() and find() as per my further edit.